# How do I read a DLLs version number in MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild

How do I read a DLLs version number in MSBuild and place it into a variable for use later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [GetAssemblyIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164296.aspx) task.

```
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="MyDll.dll">
        <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="myAssemblyInfo"/>
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
```

`%(myAssemblyInfo.Version)` will provide the DLL version.